# Reflection invoke skips rest of code

Tags: java, reflection

I can not figure out what I am doing wrong. I have 2 methods, this one which works:

```
protected void applySelection(String adjustment, String action){
    if(!adjustment.equals("") || !action.equals("")){
        try{
            ClassLoader myClassLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
            String myPackage = this.getClass().getPackage().getName();
            String classNameToBeLoaded = myPackage + "." + action + "." + adjustment;
            Class adjust = myClassLoader.loadClass(classNameToBeLoaded);
            Object whatInstance = adjust.newInstance();
            adjust.getMethod("setBitmap", new Class[]{Bitmap.class}).invoke(whatInstance, new Object[]{this.stage.getImage()});
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)adjust.getMethod("applyFilter").invoke(whatInstance);
            if(bmp != null){
                Edit.this.stage.setStageImage(bmp);
                Edit.this.stage.showTopItems(bmp);
            }
        }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
        }catch(IllegalAccessException e){
        }catch(InvocationTargetException e){
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

then this one which doesn't work:

```
protected void setFromSlider(String adjustment, String action){
    if(!adjustment.equals("") || !action.equals("")){
        try{
            ClassLoader myClassLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
            String myPackage = this.getClass().getPackage().getName();
            String classNameToBeLoaded = myPackage + "." + action + "." + adjustment;
            Class adjust = myClassLoader.loadClass(classNameToBeLoaded);
            Object whatInstance = adjust.newInstance();
            Object returnVal = adjust.getMethod("isSeekBar").invoke(whatInstance);
            if(returnVal == true){
                // Do something
            }else{
                // Do something else
            }
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            e.getMessage();
        }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
            e.getMessage();
        }catch(IllegalAccessException e){
            e.getMessage();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

On this line (in the second method):
`Object returnVal = adjust.getMethod("isSeekBar").invoke(whatInstance);`

when It gets here, it just skips over my if statement and goes directly to the closing brace of the method. What is causing that? Here is the method that is being called:

```
public boolean isSeekBar(){
    return true;
}
```

I am assuming that it is throwing an error, but none of the catch statements are catching one. I am now stumped...

Comment: May be some exception occured?

Comment: In your `catch` blocks, you are retrieving the exception message and doing nothing with it. Try logging the message to `System.err`

Comment: For each catch statement, I did System.err.append(e.getMessage()); and nothing was sent to the error console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try catching the more generic [Throwable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) - if this function is executed in the UI thread you will not see the exception.

```
try{
     ...
}catch(Throwable e){
   // e.getMessage(); this would not print anything
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

in any case, `if(returnVal == true){` does not compile (Incompatible operand types Object and boolean)

Use `if (returnVal.equals(true)) {`

Comment: Thanks! that fixes the Incompatibility thing, but still doesn't fix original issue. What is the generic Throwable? I am still really new to Java.

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify. By the way, I ran your code and it works for me. Also, `e.getMessage()` would not print anything

Comment: Your right, it does work. I restarted Netbeans and the code suddenly started to work the way I was expecting.